# TinyMCE Pagespeed Avoid "document.write" Warning

Tags: tinymce

Google Pagespeed is pointing out our tinymce.js for using dynamically injecting `document.write()` which can delay page load by tens of seconds.

We are using version 3.5.8 without customizations.

Any idea how to fix this?

Best regards,
Jane

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE 3.x has not been a supported/developed release of TinyMCE for years now so unless you wanted to attempt to modify the source code of TinyMCE yourself there is really no way to get this "fixed".

TinyMCE's current release is 5.6 so I would start by using the most recent release and seeing if that has any issues.  If it does you can report them to TinyMCE at our GitHub Issue tracker:  https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues